# Firebase functions sporadically don't complete execution

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have built a firebase cloud function that is triggered by a Firestore "document create" event

The function connects to a MongoDB cluster (running on MongoDB Atlas), modifies the Firestore data stores it in a collection on the database

The function itself executes every time on every document write

But it doesn't complete execution and this is sporadic e.g. 1 out of 10 approximately, executions will not complete i.e. neither the line "error connecting" or "connected successfully" is executed

The same code is executed the other 9/10 times (approximately)

here is a stripped down version of the code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

exports.migrate = functions.firestore
    .document('{rootCollection}/{tenantName}/users/{userId}/entry/{entryId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    console.log("Attempting to connect to mongoclient");

    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {

        if (err) {
                console.log("error connecting");
                return 1;
            }        
            else if (client) {
              console.log("Connected to mongoclient");
              //write to mongodb collection here
            }
       });
});
```

Here is a successful execution, with the log messages in red highlighting the code inside the block that executes after the MongoClient connection (with some extra log msgs printed)

[image]

Here is an unsuccessful execution

[image]

**Edit:**

Tipped by Doug's answer, this is how I solved it - not only do we need to return a promise but chain the promise returned by the connection and insert statements both

```
exports.migrate = functions.firestore
.document('{rootCollection}/{tenantName}/users/{userId}/entry/{entryId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    console.log("Attempting to connect to mongoclient");

    return MongoClient.connect(uri).then((client) => {
        console.log("Connected successfully");
        return client.db("test")
            .collection("testcollection")
            .insertOne({"name": "1"})
                .then((() => {
                    console.log("inserted successfully");
                    client.close(true)
                        .then(()=>{console.log("connection close OK")})
                        .catch(()=>{console.log("connection close Err")});
                }))
                .catch(() => {
                    console.log("error in insertion");
                    client.close(true)
                        .then(()=>{console.log("connection close OK")})
                        .catch(()=>{console.log("connection close Err")});
                });

    })
    .catch(() => console.log("connection failure"));
```

And I am sure this time since the code executes in the order I want since I can see them in the cloud-function log:

1. Function started (system message)
2. Attempting to connect (user message)
3. Connected successfully (user message)
4. Inserted successfully (user message)
5. Connection closed (user message)
6. Function ended (system message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a promise that resolves only after all the work is complete in your function.  `MongoClient.connect()` is almost certainly an asynchronous function that returns immediately, and the callback you pass to it is executed some time later.  Because it returns immediately, your database trigger returns immediately, and Cloud Functions assumes that its work is complete.  It seems only occasionally your callback is invoked before Cloud Functions shuts down your function.